# How does Flame Charge in Larvesta work?

Tags: pokemon

I don't understand the instruction for this attack. It seems to **require** one fire energy card (icon on the left), and it also says "find one fire energy card and attach it to this pokemon", which presumaly it's the instruction I get to take once I launch this attack.

But if it requires one such energy card to start with, what's the point of attaching one more to it? (AFAIK attached energy cards stay attached across turns).

What I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct of how this works (you need one energy and then this attack lets you attach another).

Larvesta can be evolved into Volcarona, for example [this Volcarona](https://m.bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Volcarona_(Crown_Zenith_25)) or [this Volcarona](https://m.bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Volcarona_(Chilling_Reign_24)), which both take more energy.

Comment: It also requires three energy card to withdrawal it from the active position.

Comment: That's true, but largely irrelevant, you're not retreating larvesta in basically any scenario. :)